# Microsoft Bot Framework - New line in prompts

Tags: node.js, botframework

How do I add a new line in a prompt?

```
session.send('This is line 1. This is line 2.');
```

I want the output to look like:

> This is line 1.
>
> This is line 2.

But the output I get is:

> This is line 1. This is line 2.

I tried using `\n`, `\r\n` and `os.EOL` but none of them worked. Is it possible to add a new line in a prompt?

Comment: What happens if you use \n\n?

Comment: Wow, that works!!!! :D Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, added the answer. Please mark it as answered/upvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try using `\n\n` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Also, is it possible to add two line spaces? `\n\n\n\n` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure, I think that they end up being ignored. You can try using <br/> and see if the html gets processed.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. But it's fine, can work with `\n\n`. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on

> single quotes ' '
>
> double quotes " "

if you use double quotes, you have to use `\n\n`

and

if you use single quotes, you have to use `<br/>`

Example,

```
session.send('This is Line 1 <br/>This is Line 2<br/>');


session.send("This is line 1\n\n This is line 2\n\n");
```